# Update with $PUSH is not working in Mongoose + Express + Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This Code is fetching JSON data from an API service correctly but not updating a nested document in `MongoDB`, Almost tried everthing

```
 api.squad(matchid, function(datapack) { 
   var data = JSON.parse(datapack);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.squad.length; i++) {
      players = data.squad[i].players;

      for(var j = 0; j < players.length; j++){

        console.log(players[j]);  // Working Fine Till here , Data from api showing here in console

        var player = { pid: players[j].pid, name: players[j].name };
        squadModel.update(              
          { leagueId: leagueId }, 
          {$push: {players: player} }       // This Update is Not Working
        );

      }
    }
  });
```

The Schema  Is As Follows for the code.

```
    // Squad Players  -- Sub Schema of Squad
var squadPlayersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    pid:{
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    name:{
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    type:{
        type: String,
    },
    cost:{
        type: Number,
    },
    country:{
        type: String,
    },
    status : {
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    }
  });


// Squad Schema
var squadSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    leagueId:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref :'leagueModel',
        required: true
    },
    players : [squadPlayersSchema],
    isLaunched : {
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    }

});

var squads = module.exports = mongoose.model('squads', squadSchema);
```

Pls help this thing has just refused to work. The update query is just working fine in `MongoDB` GUI `Studio3T` Shell

Example Of a demo query run in `Studio3T` and works fine and updates the document with the code above doesn't.

```
db.squads.update(
              { "leagueId": ObjectId("5a85900d8b3b30165875ff0d") }, 
              {
                "$push": {
                  "players":  { pid: 1234567, name: "Some Name" }
                }
              }
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each)** with **[`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)** as follows:

```
api.squad(leagueId, datapack => { 
    const data = JSON.parse(datapack);
    let updates = []; // array to hold updates promises

    data.squad.forEach(squad => { // iterate the data.squad array to get the players list

        let promise = squadModel.findOneAndUpdate(              
            { leagueId: leagueId }, 
            { '$addToSet': { 'players': { '$each': squad.players } } },
            { 'upsert': true }
        ); // update operation as a promise
        updates.push(promise);
    });

    Promise.all(updates).then(console.log).catch(console.error); // resolves when all of the updates promises have resolved 
});
```

Comment: Thank You for your time but somehow adding {safe: true} after $PUSH followed by a comma made it to work  now everything is working as expected, will try your suggestion too.......i would be great if you can tell what this safe: true thing does and why my code now works with that. the funny thing is when i run this code in GUI it doesn't need this {safe:true} thing.

Comment: I found the solution from this blogpost : http://blog.ocliw.com/2012/11/25/mongoose-add-to-an-existing-array/